# Launcher Icon is not visible for Flutter App. on Menu

Tags: flutter

I have below pubspec.yaml file & when i do **flutter run** , it launches app on device but i cannot see the launcher icon in my phone's menu listing.
My phone is Android 7

```
name: simpleapp
description: Simple App
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Check AndroidMenifest.xml, you should have icon & label there

Answer (score 0):

You could use [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) which is replacing every icons for iOS and Android (as well as Android 8.0 and more with adaptive icons) with a single command in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

- Add [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)  package to your pubspec.yaml file
- Within pubspec.yaml file specify the path of the icon you wish to use for the app and then choose whether you want to use the icon for the iOS app, Android app or both.
- Run the package
- here you go !

Answer (score 0):

More for me for the next time I have this (2nd app, 2nd time...) In android > app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml:

```
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" MUST BE kept as is. It's referencing Flutter for some magic to happen behind the scene...